# Simple XML Reader não funciona corretamente

Tags: php, xml, xml-schema, simplexml

Tenho utilizado o [SimpleXMLReader](https://github.com/dkrnl/SimpleXMLReader)

para tentar extrair dados da seguinte estrutura XML:

```
 <boutique>
       <produto num="228122907">
            <id_produto><![CDATA[70427038]]></id_produto>
            <nome><![CDATA[Solução Antirrugas - Kit]]></nome>
            <descricao><![CDATA[A melhor combinação do Pegolift com Vitamina C elevada ao extremo e as pluri funções do Pluri-Active. Experimente estes agentes.]]></descricao>
       </produto>
</boutique>
```

Mas só estou sendo capaz de exibir o valor do nódulo "num" apenas, obtendo este resultado:

```
/boutique/produto: 228122907 = 0;
/boutique/produto: 285823820 = 0;
/boutique/produto: 285823824 = 0;
/boutique/produto: 285823825 = 0;
/boutique/produto: 285823826 = 0;
/boutique/produto: 285823827 = 0;
```

Não importa o que eu altere, eu não consigo, por exemplo, extrair o valor do nódulo `<nome>`.
Estou utilizando esse software por que estou lidando com um arquivo XML muito grande.

Baixe o arquivo XML aqui: `http://v2.afilio.com.br/aff/aff_get_boutique.php?boutiqueid=37930-895987&token=53e355b0a09ea0.74300807&progid=1010&format=XML`

Baixe o software SimpleXMLReader aqui: `https://github.com/dkrnl/SimpleXMLReader`

Meu código é o seguinte:

```
<?php
header ("Content-type: text/html, charset=utf-8;");
require_once dirname(__FILE__). "/simplexmlreader.php";
class ExampleXmlReader1 extends SimpleXMLReader
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // by node name

        $this->registerCallback("nome", array($this, "callbackPrice"));
        // by xpath<br />
///////////////////// Nesta parte não mexe
        $this->registerCallback("/boutique/produto", array($this, "callbackRest"));
    }
    protected function callbackPrice($reader)
    {
        $xml = $reader->expandSimpleXml();
        $attributes = $xml->attributes();
        $ref = (string) $attributes->{"num"};
        if ($ref) {
            $price = floatval((string)$xml);
            $xpath = $this->currentXpath();
            echo "$xpath: $ref = $price;\n";
        }
        return true;
    }
    protected function callbackRest($reader)
    {
        $xml = $reader->expandSimpleXml();
        $attributes = $xml->attributes();
        $ref = (string) $attributes->{"num"};
        if ($ref) {
            $rest = floatval((string) $xml);
            $xpath = $this->currentXpath();
            echo "$xpath: $ref = $rest;\n";
        }
        return true;
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
$file = dirname(__FILE__) . "/boutique.xml";
$reader = new ExampleXmlReader1;
$reader->open($file);
$reader->parse();
$reader->close();
```

Comment: Tente rodar um foreach no $xml... pelo que entendi na documentação no GIT, é ele quem retorna os nodes no formato SimpleXMLElement object.
Tem outras funções para simplificar esse processo também.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi o primeiro callback é para buscar pelo nome do nó e o segundo callback pelo caminho do nó, como você quer o valor do nós "nome", então ficaria assim:

```
<?php
header ("Content-type: text/html, charset=utf-8;");
require_once dirname(__FILE__). "/simplexmlreader.php";
class ExampleXmlReader1 extends SimpleXMLReader
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // by node name
        $this->registerCallback("nome", array($this, "callbackPrice"));

    }
    protected function callbackPrice($reader)
    {
        $xml = $reader->expandSimpleXml();
        $name = $xml;
        $xpath = $this->currentXpath();
        echo "$xpath: Nome = $name;\n";
        return true;
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
$file = dirname(__FILE__) . "/boutique.xml";
$reader = new ExampleXmlReader1;
$reader->open($file);
$reader->parse();
$reader->close();
```

Comment: Bom é quando o cara pode responder sem testar! Mandou bem, +1

Comment: Estou testando, vou ver se consigo extrair mais de uma Node.

Comment: Se você quiser o valor de outro nó é só chamar o callback novamente com o valor do nó, por exemplo pro "id_produto": $this->registerCallback("id_produto", array($this, "callbackPrice"));

Comment: Muito obrigado a todos e especialmente ao Olavo Holanda, meu problema foi resolvido. Eu só gostaria de acrescentar que "callbackPrice" precisa ser alterado como identificador.

Comment: Exemplo: `callbackNome`

Comment: Só mais 2 dúvidas aqui, se possível me responda por favor:
1 - Como faço para limitar o numero de items retirados do XML? Por exemplo, se quiser retirar apenas 5 produtos do catálogo.
2 - Ali em `$file = dirname(__FILE__) . "/boutique.xml";`, eu preciso usar a URL do XML `http://v2.afilio.com.br/aff/aff_get_boutique.php?boutiqueid=37930-895987&token=53e355b0a09ea0.74300807&progid=1010&format=XML` ao invés do arquivo local.

Comment: 1 - Acredito que você terá que modificar o código do SimpleXMLReader e passar algum parâmetro novo para limitar, não vi maneiras de fazer isso sem modificar o SimpleXMLReader. 2 - Na linha onde tem $reader->open($file); troca o $file pela string da URL do XML. $reader->open("http://v2.afilio.com.br/aff/aff_get_boutique.php?boutiqueid=37930-895987&token=53e355b0a09ea0.74300807&progid=1010&format=XML");

Comment: Encontrei outro problema, não estou conseguindo converter os valores em HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução bem simples que retorna seu XML como um array em PHP:

```
<?php

$xml = '<boutique><produto num="228122907"><id_produto><![CDATA[70427038]]></id_produto><nome><![CDATA[Solução Antirrugas - Kit]]></nome><descricao><![CDATA[A melhor combinação do Pegolift com Vitamina C elevada ao extremo e as pluri funções do Pluri-Active. Experimente estes agentes.]]></descricao></produto></boutique>';
$xml_file_data = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xml, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA),true), true);

print_r($xml_file_data);
```

**Retorno da execução do código:**
[image: Retorno]